# .htaccess rewriterule to not redirecting specific url

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I wrote rules to rewrite url

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ news.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ news.php?id=$1
```

but I need that `http://mysite.com/blog/` not to be rewritten by these rules.
Thanks for you advices :).

My .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !news\.php [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/blog [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+) [NC] 
RewriteRule .* news.php?id=%1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteRule ^video_([^/]+) video.php?page=Video&table=$1 
RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ en/news_en.php?no=$1 
RewriteRule ^en/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ en/news_en.php?no=$1 
RewriteRule ^it/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ it/news.php?id=$1 
RewriteRule ^it/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/$ it/news.php?id=$1 

RewriteRule ^photo_([^/]+) photogalery.php?page=Photo&part=$1 
RewriteRule ^en/photo_([^/]+) en/photogalery.php?page=Photo&part=$1 
RewriteRule ^it/photo_([^/]+) it/photogalery.php?page=Photo&part=$1 
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Comment: What's the domain part in the incoming URL, is it `mysite.com` too?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ news.php?id=$1
```